# Android Inserting Special Characters

Tags: android, special-characters, font-face

I am getting unsupported special characters randomly injected into my text, these only show up on Android devices, and there is no special character where they appear. Some are added after the opening tag, others before the closing tag.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkyiX.png)

Comment: for example what type of text / character ??

Comment: I included a screenshot, there is no character there, it somehow gets added

Comment: put your code and output.